# How can I have a MySQL connection globally available for the entire application

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a NodeJS backend. I am using the mysql plugin (not the connector X API)  to connect to the database. I want to open a connection at application start and make the connection available for all the APIs in the application rather than a separate connection per module. How can I do that?

The database connection is in a separate javascript file with the follwing code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.HOST,
  user: process.env.USER,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('[SERVER] Database connection established..');
});

module.exports = connection;
```

I want something like creating the connection in `index.js` rather than separate controller modules.

**Edit:**
I have put a console.log at the first line of each file. This is the order the files are being loaded.

[image]

This is my index.js file (this is the entry point of the app)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv').config();

const db = require('./src/utils/DatabaseConnection');
db.establishConnection();

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`[SERVER] Up and running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

and this is how I am calling the established connection in the RegisterController.js file

```
const database = require('../../utils/DatabaseConnection');
const connection = database.getConnection();
/* Rest of the code*/
```

Q.1 If I am calling the `establishConnection()` method before the server starts, then why is `[SERVER] Database connection established..` message being logged after the server running at port message?

Q.2 Is there a specific way to how the files of a Node.js application loaded in the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more readable to have a separate file for db connection.
Since you want it in the index.js itself, you can have it like this

```
app.use('/users/list', usersList(connection))
```

In this manner, you will have the connection as the parameter in the `usersList` function. So, `usersList` will be as

```
exports.usersList = (connection) => {
  // your database operation
}
```

You can also pass additional params for the function.

I would still recommend you to have separate file for database config and connection. That separate file can look something like this

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
var _connection;

exports.createConnection = (_connection) => {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
  });
  _connection = connection;

  connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('[SERVER] Database connection established..');
  });
}};

exports.getConnection = () => {
  return _connection;
}
```

Edit: About the logs getting printed later, it is because starting the server requires no connections or other system processes, However, establishing a connection works async and so by the time it is done, your server is already up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also want the connection to be in a separate file but I want to connect to the database as early as possible (immediately after server starts) and then I want to use the connection where it's required. I want a single connection throughout the application runtime. I don't want to create a new connection every time I load a different module with a set of APIs.

Comment: yes. so both these methods use the same connection. If it is in another file, you can call `createConnection` from that file in the first few lines of index.js so that the connection is established. Later, you can use `getConnection` to get the same connection and pass it to `app.use()`. It is kind of mixture of the above 2 solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still having a hard time grasping this concept. I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: printing of the logs itself takes time. It will be a matter of just few ms.